# Python: How to show progress bar for scikit-learn OneVsRestClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am training a OneVsRestClassifier with a training set size of around 10000, and somehow it just keeps running, so I want to see if there's a way for it to show the training progress, like a progress bar.

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(C=1.0, kernel='rbf', gamma=1.0, probability=True))
```

This doesn't show anything, then I tried adding verbose=True when initiating the model. All it shows is [LibSVM].., and I still can't tell the progress. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: There are some classifiers which show verbose output. However OVR is not one of them. Try making n_jobs=-1, which might speed up the training.